# Load XML-content into li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xml

I have a ul-list like that:

```
<ul class="abstimm_ziel"><li>Content 1</li><li>Content 2</li></ul>
```

And I want to load this xml-files' content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abstimmer>
<seite id="2">
    <klick>3</klick>
    <klick>5</klick>
    <klick>9</klick>
</seite>
</abstimmer>
```

into the li-elements according to its order (first node goes into first li-element, second into second...). If there are more nodes then li-elements, then the unnecessary nodes shall be ignored. I try doing this by so:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "abstimmer.xml", 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: function (xml) { 
            $(xml).find('seite').each(function () { 
                var klick = $(this).find('klick'); 
                $( ".abstimm_ziel li" ).each(function( index ) {
                    //And here my brain  crashed
                })
            })
        }
    })
})
```

In the line where the real action should start, I broke up. What I tried to do, is walk through the ul-list with each() and put the content of the xml of the appropriate node into the li in it.  What do I need to do now?

Comment: When you say "first node goes into first li-element", which node are you talking about, the first `seite` node or the first `klick` node? If it's each `klick`, then you should iterator over those, and just use `eq`, like `$(xml).find('klick').each(function (index) { $(".abstimm_ziel li").eq(index).html($(this).text()); })`... Or something similar.

Comment: It's the first klick-node. And 
$(".abstimm_ziel li").eq(index).html($(this).text()); } 
would replace "Content 1" with "3" - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking at the `klick` nodes, I would just use the [`eq` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq) like this:

```
var $lis = $(".abstimm_ziel li");
$(xml).find('klick').each(function (index) {
  if (index < $lis.length) {
    $lis.eq(index).html($(this).text());
  }
});
```

This will iterate through all of the `klick` nodes, and if there is a matching `li` in the DOM, set its contents to the content of the `klick` node.